# POST method resulting status code 400 ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, api

I have tried many times, but i cant do a simple POST request to a remote API.. I need to post username and password to get a login authorization. Here are the code:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://thapi.xyz/auth/login"];
NSString *postData = @"username=emailExample@gmail.com&password=123456";
NSData * dataBody = [postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLenght = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[dataBody length]];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-unlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:postLenght forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Lenght"];
[request setHTTPBody:dataBody];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable connectionError) {
    NSLog(@" ERROR %@, RESPONSE %@ AND DATA %@",connectionError,response,[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
}];
```

I have made another version, witch uses NSDictionary and Json parsing (the API uses json)

```
NSDictionary * login = @{@"username":@"exampleMail@gmail",@"password":@"123456"};
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:login options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *postLenght = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[jsonData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-unlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:postLenght forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Lenght"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable connectionError) {
  NSLog(@" ERROR %@, RESPONSE %@ AND DATA %@",connectionError,response,[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
}];
```

And here is the result of both codes:

```
    2016-06-18 05:24:20.329 Hoffmann iOS[10317:1088208]
    ERROR (null), RESPONSE <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x796bee60> 
    { URL: http://thapi.xyz/auth/login } { status code: 400, headers {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
        Connection = "keep-alive";
        "Content-Length" = 70;
        "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        Date = "Sat, 18 Jun 2016 04:24:18 GMT";
        Etag = "W/\"46-22Kcj8zTKrWgQ7OCr429+w\"";
        Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
        Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
        "X-Powered-By" = undefined;
        "X-Response-Time" = "5.357ms";
    } } AND DATA {"name":"ParameterError","message":"Request should contain: username"}
```

I really appreciate all answers, and sorry for my bad english...

Comment: try this This may work not sure     [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

Comment: The `username` parameter is invalid according to the error message; It should likely be something like `@"UserName=%@&Password=%@",username,pass`, etc...

Comment: Thank you for the comments! The api receive only POST, so as expected i give a shot with GET and doesn't work.. And the param problem, i have try but the stack trace keeps the same :/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the misspelling of the header variable is the issue ("Content-Lenght" is misspelled):

```
[request setValue:postLenght forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

Comment: Thank you for warning me of this misspelling problem! But, unfortunately, that was not the problem.. The stack trace keep the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection  is deprecated. use nsurlsession instead Try this code....

```
//replace the following code with your request params
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *clientSessionId = [prefs stringForKey:@"clientSession"];

        NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[\"%@\",{\"session_token\":\"%@\",\"request\":[\"GetUnitDetails\",{}]}]",clientSessionId,clientSessionId];
        //Make mutable url request        
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Settings getMobileUrl]]];
        NSData *postData = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    //Change the http method as per your own choice
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


        [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *connectionError)
          {
              if ([data length] > 0 && connectionError == nil)

              {
         NSError *localError = nil;
        self.parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&localError];
        NSString* unitResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *jsonData = [unitResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableArray *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];   




                  }else {
    NSLog(@"No response received");
}

          }]resume];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But, that was not the problem.. The stack trace keep the same thing.. Im start wondering thats the problem is in the API, although this is almost impossible...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `NSDictionary` for the parameters. The following will send the parameters correctly to a JSON server.

```
NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://thapi.xyz/auth/login"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSDictionary *login = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"username":@"exampleMail@gmail",@"password":@"123456",
                     nil];
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:login options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

Hope this works Properly...:)

Comment: I really thank you for the answer, but thats changes nothing at all in the stack trace.. keep the same error 400 with the same message :(

Answer (score 0):

try also to correct "setValue:postLenght", since I guess that doesn't exist, and will probably set Content-Length to 0.

Comment: Failing that, use wireshark to see what is being sent.